# Show div on mouseover over another div and close all other divs with same class

Tags: jquery

I have a list of divs (simplified example)

```
<div class="title">text</div>
<div class="description">text</div>
<div class="title">text</div>
<div class="description">text</div>
<div class="title">text</div>
<div class="description">text</div>
```

`.description`  is hidden on page load
when I hover over a title i show the description to that title, when I hover over another title I show the description to that title, but what I also want to do is to hide that last `.description` that was open.

I tried with `mouseout`, `mouseleave` etc. but didn't get it to work. Any suggestions?

```
    $('.title').mouseover(function () {
            $(this).next().fadeIn('fast');
        });

        $('.title')..mouseleave(function () {
            $(this).next().slideOut('fast');
        });
```

With this I hide the description if I hover over the same title again but not other titles.

```
    jQuery.fn.fadeToggle = function (speed, easing, callback) {
        return this.animate({ opacity: 'toggle' }, speed, easing, callback);
    };

    $('.title').mouseover(function () {
            $(this).next().fadeToggle('fast');
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify their class selector to hide them all, in this way only one of them will be shown at a time:

```
   $('.title').mouseover(function () {
     $('.description').hide();
     $(this).next().fadeIn('fast');
   });
```

Comment: ahh too easy, thanks (have to wait a couple of min to accept solution)

Comment: once I have started to show any description there will always be one shown, is there a way to hide all descriptions if I don't have had the mouse over a .title or .description for some time?

Comment: @martin: You can use the mouseleave method similarly and hide all description elements like I showed :)

Comment: yeah I realized that, I have a link at the bottom of the description divs though so if I leave .title to click on the link the div becomes hidden which isn't very good. Sorry for not posting this information in my original question.

Comment: ok so I wrap it in an additional div and add mouseleave to that one.

Answer (score 0):

You've made a typo here:

```
$('.title')..mouseleave(function () {
```

There's two periods.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works if you use the right function. There is **no** `slideOut` method. Use either *[`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)* or *[`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)*, e.g.:

```
$('.title').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).next().fadeIn('fast');
});

$('.title').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).next().fadeOut('fast');
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Tjcvz/

Comment: thanks for the comment, I didn't see your reply until after I tried Sarfraz solution.